# In an Angular 7.2.2 app, Webpack tells me to replace System.import() with import(), but that gives errors. How do I fix?

Tags: webpack, import, angular7

So I upgraded an Angular app from Angular version 5.2.5 to 7.2.2, using the instructions found at the update.angular.io website.

I know this updated TypeScript and Webpack and all the other stuff that goes along with Angular apps.  I'm not knowledgeable enough to know precisely what versions of these things were foisted upon me, however.

But everything runs fine -- *except* whatever version of Webpack this thing installed gives me warnings.  "System.import() is deprecated and will be removed soon. Use import() instead."

So I change "System.import()" to "import()".

At which point, I start to get errors:  "Dynamic import is only supported when '--module' flag is 'commonjs' or 'esNext'"

I have googled both the warning and the error message, and I can't make heads or tails of any of the supposed "solutions."  Webpack is apparently used in a great many things other than Angular, and I cannot specifically find a way of dealing with this problem in an Angular 7.2.2 app.  The "solutions" talk about editing config files that don't exist or don't look at all like what the examples say they should look like.

So how do I get rid of the warnings, without causing these errors?  Why can I not just change "System.import()" to "import()" like Webpack tells me to?

Very frustrated. Any help would be appreciated.